# "Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.tools.ij" on Eclipse when trying to run derby

Tags: java, database, eclipse, macos, derby

I am all very new to database systems. I am trying to connect derby to Eclipse by passing in this command

```
    java org.apache.derby.tools.ij
```

under the external tools configurations in the "Arguments" section. I have set the location to

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

and the error is that it  "Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.tools.ij".

I have tried using javac and javadoc but still, have had no success. Also, I have and OS machine.

Ideally, when this is set up properly I can start inserting to the database when I see ij> in the console.

Comment: Could you check the path of project. The gist is eclipse do not expect space in between the paths(folders location) of the project. Give it a try.

Comment: @Ashutosh I am not trying to run a project just simply trying to add derby as an external tool. After that I would be able to pass SQL statements in the console of eclipse

Comment: Since you're new to database systems, try this very useful Getting Started tutorial for Derby: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/getstart/

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a classpath, either using a command line argument or by setting it into the environment, so that the `java` command knows where to find the main class you want it to run.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html or run `java -help` for a short guide of its common arguments.